# Log for the root directory of an external HDD

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, crash, hdd

I really doubt that this would be possible, but is there any chance that OS X 10.7.5 logs the root directory contents of an external HDD that was plugged in through a USB drive a week ago?

My external HDD died and I would like to retrieve the info of what folders it contained just to know if it worth 800 USD to get it fixed.

Comment: I doubt it's worth fixing for 800USD if you didn't create back-ups... and no, there is no such log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there is no log of such.

The data, such a spotlight DB, is stored on the drive itself.